# ClickOnce publish with different update locations for customers

Tags: installation, clickonce, publish

I have a WPF application that needs to go out to lots of customers.  I want to give them the files which they can then distribute to their users to install.  I also would like to have the program update automatically.

I initially thought that ClickOnce was the way to go but have come into some problems.  It would work fine if all the update locations were the same but they are not, the customer would choose where the files go, either to a web site or file share.  The only way I can see of using this way is to create different versions for each customer with their update path set, which is not really acceptable.

I am also considering Wix as an installer instead, but as this will require a lot more work than ClickOnce I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish what I want using ClickOnce first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same scenario, and I guess we should let the customers to create and sign their own Deployment Menifest which specifies the update location. See the walkthrough here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384246.aspx